# exception in thread main java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I' m kind of new to Java, and for homework I got this exercise:

> write a java program which can take a word from the keyboard and show it reversed `("hello" --> "olleh")`

And this is how I wrote the program

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Inverti {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("digiti una parola o una frase, essa sara' stampata a video alla              rovescia");
     Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
     String invertire = tastiera.nextLine();
     for (int i = 0; i < invertire.length();) {
     invertire.replace(invertire.charAt(i), invertire.charAt(invertire.length() - i));
     i++;
         }
System.out.print(invertire);
}
}
```

(I'm Italian, so consider that "tastiera" means "keyboard" and "digiti una parola o una frase, essa sarà stampata a video alla rovescia" means "type a word, it will be shown reversed")

The program gets compiled, but then, after typing the word:

```
exception in thread main java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception: string 
    index out of bounds: 6 (if string.length() is 6) or 5 (if string.length() = 5).
```

I looked for answers to other similar questions before posting, but nothing helped me, sorry if the question' s format maybe isn't right.

Comment: What has Windows-8 got to do with this?

Comment: The value of `i` is 0 at the first iteration. So `charAt(invertire.length()-i)` will throw the exception.

Comment: `replace` returns a new String, you should assign the result.

Comment: You should always indicate the specific line that was flagged in the exception traceback.  (Not that it's hard to figure out here.)

Comment: Understand that in Java a String object is immutable, meaning that any manipulation you do on a String (such as `replace`) does not modify THAT string but instead returns a new String which you must assign somewhere.

Comment: FYI: Take a look at this piece of code for your problem. `for ( int i = invertire.length() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )`

Answer (score 1):

In case your line is 6 length long that means the range of possibilities are [0, 5].
Then if we take `i` as 0 and `invertire` as 6 will get the following evaluation:

```
invertire.charAt(6 - 0)
```

The result is of course `invertire.charAt(6)` that doesn't appears in the range, and it's what causing the exception.

Fix:

```
invertire.charAt(invertire.length() - i - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = tastiera.nextLine();
StringBuilder inverse = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length();i++) {
inverse.append(input.charAt(input.length()-1-i));
}
System.out.print(inverse);
```

Comment: If you're using a `StringBuilder`, why don't you simply do `String inverse = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();` ?

Comment: yes thats the easiest way to achieve String reversal. I was not trying to take a short cut here.